# Gibt es ein Verb zum Substantiv "Mediation"?

Tags: single-word-request

Es gibt das Hauptwort *Mediation* mit der Bedeutung

> aussöhnende Vermittlung zwischen den Interessen verschiedener Personen;
>   Technik zur Bewältigung von Konflikten durch unparteiische Beratung

Gibt es zu diesem Wort das entsprechende Verb? Wenn ja, wie lautet es?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Über [Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=mediieren&service=canooNet) bin ich zu *mediieren* gelangt. Duden und Konsorten führen es nicht auf, eine Google-Suche hingegen zeigt, dass es immerhin ab und an verwendet wird.

Comment: +1 ich kenne einige Mediatoren - mediieren ist das richtige Wort. Weil es eher unbekannt ist und nicht sonderlich gut von der Zunge geht, nutzt man es doch eher selten, sondern greift auf Ausweichkonstrukte wie "Mediation durchführen" etc. zurück.

Comment: @Jan ja, das Wort scheint zumindest eine gewisse Verbreitung zu haben, auch wenn ich finde, dass es etwas seltsam klingt. Außerdem gibt es anscheinend auch eine zweite, medizinische Bedeutung: http://www.google.com/search?q=mediieren+medizinisch

Comment: @splattne ja, wobei die grundlegende Bedeutung die gleiche sein dürfte, nämlich *vermitteln*.

Comment: *Mediieren* wird von Mediatoren selbst benutzt, ich finde es aber sprachlich sehr unschön. Man kann *vermitteln* sagen, wenn es einem nicht auf die Feinheiten ankommt oder aus dem Kontext klar wird, was gemeint ist: *Die Mediatorin vermittelte zwischen den Parteien*.

Comment: Interessant ist, dass das Wort ab dem Jahr 2000 einen Boom erlebt (vielleicht hatte es früher eine andere Bedeutung?): http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=mediieren&year_start=1800&year_end=2011&corpus=8&smoothing=3

Comment: "mediieren" ist ungewöhnlich und klingt sehr ähnlich wie "meditieren", da ist Verwirrung vorprogrammiert

Comment: @ammoQ: Klar, aber das trifft potentiell auch auf alle möglichen Homonyme zu.

Answer (score 6):

Ich würde "vermitteln" nehmen. z.B. "Ich habe versucht, zwischen der Hausverwaltung und den Mietern zu vermitteln."

Wichtig ist, die nicht reflexive Form des Verbs zu benutzen. Es gibt auch die reflexive Form "sich vermitteln", z.B. in "ich hoffe ich habe mich vermitteln können...", was so viel heißt wie "ich hoffe ich wurde verstanden." Das darf man nicht verwechseln.

Comment: Ein Ausweichwort ist keine Antwort auf die Frage.

Answer (score 5):

Im Zusammenhang mit Mediatoren kann man auch *schlichten* nutzen.

Comment: Schlichtung und Mediation sind aber [nicht das Gleiche](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation#Abgrenzungen). Wenn ich das richtig mitgeschnitten habe, wird bei der Schlichtung am Ende ein Schlichterspruch gefällt, d.h. der Schlichter wird inhaltlich tätig (siehe z.B. Stuttgart 21). Ein Mediator trifft dagegen keine inhaltlichen Entscheidungen, sondern kümmert sich rein um die Form.

Comment: Ein Ausweichwort ist keine Antwort auf die Frage.